# While already ssh'd into a remote compute node, how to transfer files to the remote computer from my local computer?

Tags: ssh, scp

I want to transfer files and scripts from my local computer (ie. my laptop) to a remote computer (a compute node of an organization). I have to ssh three times to get to that node. Once there, how can I transfer/upload the files? Other answers suggest using scp, but this seems to work the other way, to download files from the remote to the local computer, or else to upload to the remote computer without having ssh'ed in first. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems like a classic use case for an [SSH Tunnel](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) (a.k.a SSH Port Forwarding)

Comment: @user535733 Could you explain what that is / how it works? Or point me to some resource that does? Thanks!

Comment: Try the link I provided.

Comment: Oh jeez I'm an idiot. Thanks.